# Resampling with percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a data frame with some numerical values and a date-timestamp.

What I would like to do is aggregate the data into monthly intervals outputting a max percentile value for each month.

What I have been doing so far is just using:

```
df = df.resample('M', on='ds').max()
```

Which gives me the max value for that month. However, from what I can see in my data there are usually one or two spikes in each month. The result is that by using `max()` I will get that spike value - which is not correct. So I way to filter out the few high value peaks I was wondering if I could use a percentile function instead of `max()`, .e.g:

```
np.percentile(df['y'], 99)
```

As far as I can see the `resample` function does not provide the option to use own functions. But I might be wrong? In any case, how can this be accomplished ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.resample('M', on='ds')['y'].agg(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 99))
```

Comment: @George - I see it, not idea.

Comment: This worked very well, just had to add reset_index() at the end to keep the 'y' label on that column.